# Need an refutation to this alleged mistake in the holy Quran?

Tags: quran, hadith, tafseer

Quran says that mountain have pegs ( which is true) but mountains without pegs exist to, according to wikiislam (anti-Islamic page, i know) but how can we as Muslims reply to this, according to them this refutes the mountains have pegs idea,

The observation here is that they equate ‘deep mountain roots’ with ‘pegs’. There are several difficulties with this interpretation in that not all mountains have peg-like roots. An analysis of mountain formation reveals the fact that not all mountains have peg-like roots, for example volcanoes; those formed by extension and faulting (e.g. the Nevada Basin and Range); thrust and fold belts (e.g. Appalachians, Eastern Bolivian Andes, Zagros Mountain, the Calcareous Alps). A cross-section of the collisional Himalayas reveals a broad ‘wedge’ rather than Cailleux’s schematic ‘peg’ diagram,[5] as do the Pyrenees.[6]

Comment: Volcano != Mountain. Unless I am not understanding you correctly.

Comment: It would be nice to add the Verse(s) of the Quran which you are talking about

Comment: Dear Movve, I found a related issue, In'Sha'Allah I with provide an appropriate answer for it whenever I got free. (God willing in these minutes or next hour). / Of course it would be good as  @Medi said"It would be nice to add the Verse(s) of the Quran which you are talking about " / Anyhow I'll submit my answer.

Comment: Maybe you  this could be helpful http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25975/is-it-possible-for-the-quran-to-have-mistakes-in-it/25986#25986

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you asked, I didn’t find the precise verse as what you mentioned. Even apparently there is not such a verse as much as I make research. (Although there would be an answer for it was really was available). In the meantime, as @Medi said:

> It would be nice to add the Verse(s) of the Quran which you are
>   talking about

Since as you named. “anti-islamic page” brought it up, and perhaps they intend to make a hesitation or doubt regarding that in the mind of Muslims and non-Muslims as a Shobha. Anyhow, based on what I researched, the most related verse with what you pointed out (and probably the purposed verse) is the following verse (السوره النباء 7 & 6):

> أَلَمْ نَجْعَلِ الْأَرْضَ مِهَادًا ﴿٦﴾ وَالْجِبَالَ أَوْتَادًا ﴿٧
>
> Have We not made the earth a resting place? (6) And the mountains as
>   stakes? (7)

- Consequently, as you see at the verse 7, it is said that “And the
  mountains as stakes? (7)” So, to the best of my knowledge (and based
  on what I saw in my research, it is mentioned the mountains as the
  stakes for the earth. In other word, it means mountains are
  considered as stakes which are between the earth and Sky. Therefore
  it is inferred from the verse that it is related to the E’jaaz
  (miracle) of the Quran that connect or keep the earth by the
  mountains as stakes which are invisibly connected to the sky.
- Or as another reason, as another aspect, it can be declared that the
  holy Quran doesn’t mean that their shapes are exactly like pegs,
  haply it would declare that they have a similar role with the pegs
  (as stakes). In the meantime, some of current scientist believe that
  the balancing role of the mountains is necessary in the keeping the
  vita on the earth. Actually they can have the role of the pegs which
  keep from shaking …
- And it can have many other reasons. We ought not to forget that there
  are many mysteries in the holy Quran that human are not aware
  concerning them…

---

Eventually, I strongly recommend you to read the following link which has illustrated more detailed regarding the mentioned matter. (Which is into Persian, Indonesian and Turkish.

[www.islamquest.net / Indonesian](http://www.islamquest.net/id/archive/question/fa4549) / [Turkish](http://www.islamquest.net/tr/archive/question/fa4549) / [Persian (Farsi)](http://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa4549)

---

**References:**

- [www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa4549)
- [quran.al-shia.org](http://quran.al-shia.org/fa/id/26/6/169.htm)
- [tadabbor.org](http://tadabbor.org/?page=tadabbor&SOID=78&AYID=7)